# How to prevent bot following GET form?

Tags: php, get, nofollow

I have the following form in my index.php:

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">  
    <input name="id" type="text">
</form>
```

I know that I can change the method to POST, so that googlebot (or any other bot) won't submit this. However I need this to be a GET form.

- I have set noindex and nofollow when `$_GET["id"]` is submitted (i.e. on `index.php?id=123`)
- index.php has index and follow, because I want the rest of the site to be followed and indexed.

I'm looking for a way to prevent googlebot from entering the `index.php?id='some random number'`

Comment: Did the noindex and nofollow trick not work?

Comment: I'd like that the "index.php?id=123" won't get loaded at all (unless by humans)

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple test and return a 404 header. Granted, this is not terribly efficient, but it will work for what you want

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Googlebot') !== false) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I'd like that the "index.php?id=123" won't get loaded at all (unless by humans)

Comment: Then expand the list. Build an array of bots to exclude and then do an `array_search`